# How to use Cookies in ANDROID?

Tags: php, android, cookies

Its a login app that will ask user for its username and password and then send this data to some php script on server.This part is working properly. Now what I need is to maintain this session via cookies even if user closes this application so as to keep user logged in until and unless he logs out manually.

Following is my core code for this process

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button blogin;
public TextView content, error, link_signup;

public EditText uname, pass;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);



    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
    link_signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);

    blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);

    blogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    link_signup.setOnClickListener(this);

}


public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = uname.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        uname.setError("Enter a valid email address");
        error.setTextSize(20);
        error.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        error.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#646464"));
        error.setText("Invalid Username or Password");

        valid = false;
    } else {
        uname.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
        pass.setError("Enter a password between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
        error.setTextSize(20);
        error.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        error.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#646464"));
        error.setText("Invalid Username or Password");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        pass.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.blogin:
            validate();
            new JsonTask().execute("https://www.aboutmyclinic.com/test.php", uname.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.link_signup:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
            break;


    }

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    uname.setText("");
    pass.setText("");
    error.setText("");
    error.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}

public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;




        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("firstParam", params[1])
                    .appendQueryParameter("secondParam", params[2]);

            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


            connection.connect();






            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {

                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONObject json = null;
        String sucessvalue = null;
        String errorvalue=null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            sucessvalue = json.getString("Success");
            errorvalue=json.getString("Error");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(sucessvalue!=null) {

            Intent i = new Intent(SignIn.this, login.class);
            i.putExtra("sucessval", sucessvalue);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
            content.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

My php page looks like this:

```
<?php
$fp=$_POST['firstParam'];
$sp=$_POST['secondParam'];
if($fp=='badhe.percept@gmail.com' && $sp=='badhe')
echo "{Success:'Hellooo...'}";
else
echo "{Error:'something happened'}";
?>
```

Comment: use sharedprefrences instead of cookies

Comment: @YounasBangash How can I use it? Help me out

Answer (score 3):

I'm  using [this solution](https://gist.github.com/franmontiel/ed12a2295566b7076161). It will store your cookies in your Shared preferences. This will prevent you from losing the data if the app is closed.

Initialize it at the beginning of your app.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()),CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```